# What is the significance of Frank watching Lucas kiss Zoe?

Tags: character, analysis, house-of-cards

During season 01 episode 07 of *House of Cards*, at about 41 minutes into the episode, Lucas drunkenly stumbles into Zoe and in a half-coordinated romantic advance, kisses her.

Frank, watching in his car, makes this face:
[image]

The background music then changes to a serious tone, so this must have somehow been a significant moment—but my question is, how was it significant? What did it mean?